# Using Ansible to fetch or copy files from a remote server (using globs) to the current server results in "file not found: /tmp/data/*.zip"

Tags: permissions, wildcards, ansible

In Ansible, I want to fetch or copy zip files from remote server-B to currently logged remote server-A (both are Linux hosts). 
As you can see below,
I am specifying the source files with a wildcard (glob):

```yaml
- hosts: server-A
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: copy the zip files
    fetch:
      src: /tmp/data/*.zip
      dest: /tmp/app/
      flat: yes
    register: zip_status
    delegate_to: server-B
```

Below is the error I get; I tried with copy/synchronize module as well, it's not working. 
actually the file exist at destination server-B

```
fatal: [server-B -> 10.98.68.222]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "src": "/tmp/data/*.zip"
        }
    "msg": "file not found: /tmp/data/*.zip"
```

I tried [Tim Kennedy's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/644352/80216). 
As stated above, I first login into Server-A. 
As shown in the code above, I delegate to Server-B. 
I added another `delegate_to: server-B` line, below. 
As stated above, I want to copy .zip files from `/tmp/data/` (from Server-B)
to `/tmp/app/` (Server-A).

```yaml
- hosts: server-A
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: find the zip files
    find:
      paths: "/tmp/data"
      recurse: no
      patterns: "*.zip"
    register: zip_files
    delegate_to: server-B

  - name: copy the zip files
    fetch:
      src: "{{ item.path }}"
      dest: "/tmp/app/"
      flat: yes
    with_items: "{{ zip_files.files }}"
    register: zip_status
    delegate_to: server-B
```

Using find module, it displays the files correctly, but error using fetch module, it is trying to create directory `/tmp/app/` when already existing. full permission in place.

```
fatal: [server-A]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "Unable to create local directories(/tmp/app/): [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/tmp'"
```

Comment: What does "actually the file exist at destination server-B"  mean?

Comment: The user that ansible runs as doesn't have permission to create the local directory on server-A, /tmp/app.  You should be able to fix that by setting an ACL or using a simple chmod

Answer (score 2):

Fetch doesn't support directories or wildcards.  The documentation is pretty clear that the string will be interpreted as a filename, and only a filename.  You may be able to make it work in conjunction with a list of files provided by a separate lookup process.

Maybe something like:

```
- hosts: server-A
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: find the zip files
    find:
      paths: "/tmp/data"
      recurse: no
      patterns: "*.zip"
    register: zip_files
  - name: copy the zip files
    fetch:
      src: "{{ item.path }}"
      dest: "/tmp/app/"
      flat: yes
    with_items: "{{ zip_files.files }}"
    register: zip_status
    delegate_to: server-B
```

I'm not completely sure that this will work the way we want with the delegate_to, but it should at least get you pointed in the right direction.

Comment: In case you hadn't noticed, the OP says that they tried your suggested code and still see error; see the edit to the question.

Comment: @G-ManSays'ReinstateMonica' - thanks for the mention.  I hadn't seen the update.